# Spock Framework: Skipping Failed Test Case

Tags: groovy, spock

I want the execution to skip the test which are failing and move to the next test in the class. Since i am using @Stepwise the execution is getting stopped once any test is getting failed.

I have some test which should pass and if its failing execution should stop and other test should skip if its getting failed. Please advise how it can be possible using Spock/Groovy Framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> @Unroll

annotation which indicates that iterations of a data-driven feature should be made visible as separate features to the outside world (IDEs, reports, etc.). So even if your one case is being failed the execution will move forward to next case. then again there are several annotations that can serve your purpose

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but Spock provides several annotations that allow failing tests to be ignored, these include

- `@Ignore` Indicates that a specification or feature method should not  be run.
- `@IgnoreIf` Ignores the annotated spec or feature if the given condition holds.
- `@IgnoreRest` Indicates that all feature methods except the ones carrying this annotation should be ignored.